# $cordovaFile + $cordovaFileOpener2 do not work together

Tags: file, cordova, pdf, ionic-framework

I load a pdf file via WebSockets. Do have a native app open the pdf file i wanted to use the [$cordovaFile](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) from ngCordova to first store the file to the local filesystem and open it with the [$cordovaFileOpener2](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/). This way the file could be opened with whatever program is wanted.

The problem is, that any programm would reject to open the file with a invalid path error.

my code looks like that:

```
SomeAsysncPdfService.load().then(function(base64Pdf){
    $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "myPdf.pdf", window.atob(base64Pdf), true).then(function(event){
        // I tested to read the file with $cordovaFile.readAsDataURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, fileName); and it worked. so the file must have been written
        $cordovaFileOpener2.open(
            event.target.localURL,'application/pdf'
        );
    })
});
```

I also tried to convert the filePath from the cordova file system ([cdvfile](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2#examples)) to a regular `file://...` file without any success. It seems like the fileopener can read the path but the other program is not allowed to open a file from the apps filescope.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ?

Comment: yes I choose the external directories

Comment: Hi, can u paste your solution here? I have a similar kind of a problem.

Comment: It does actually work but you need to use the correct paths.